# How to see the stored data of Cassandra db for janusgraph database by cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, cqlsh, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am new to janusgraph as well as to janusgraph. Now I am able to connect janusgraph with cassandra as backend storage and solr and index storage Currently I am starting gremlin server by the command -  sh **gremlin-server.sh /conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server-cql-solr.yaml** and connecting it through by **sh gremlin.sh**.

I have a couple of doubts like - **graph.addVertex("name", "Arpan")** by using this i am adding the vertice. Now I found that the vertice and edge information is getting stored in the table name
**< Keyspacename>.edgestore**  and I am sure that data is getting inserted to cassandra db becuase **g.V().values('name')** is showing me the value of vertice name.
I am using cqlsh to see the Cassandra data but when I typed the cmd   **select * from keyspacename.edgestore;** Instead of showing text values like - name Arpan its showing data in numeric form like -

```
            key                | column1            | value
```

--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
0x5800000000000080 |               0x02 |      0x0001048b
0x5800000000000080 |           0x5019a0 |      0xa06a656e6ef9088b
0x5800000000000080 |           0x504ba0 |    0xa0686f6de50c8b011780a03836372d353330b9

How I can see the actual data? And should I use this default table schema or should I create my own?

Answer (score 3):

JanusGraph uses its own data format in the storage layer.  It builds the JanusGraph keyspaces and tables in the way that it needs them to be.  Therefore, you should definitely *not* create your own.

You will not be able to read the actual data from cqlsh.  To read the data, you'll have the best luck with the Gremlin console, build an [app using the (Java?) JanusGraph libraries](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java), or with a [visualizer](https://github.com/bricaud/graphexp).